# Monitoring IIS site bandwidth individually

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, bandwidth

I have a VPS (using Windows Server, IIS) with around 20 sites, of which  I would like to monitor the monthly bandwidth usage independently. Performance Monitor is useful but ideally I'd like to show someone their bandwidth usage (e.g. on their own computer) if they asked for it.

Can anyone recommend me any tools for monitoring this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the software called [Anturis](http://www.anturis.com), that deals with all kinds of monitoring issues. They can monitor networks, web apps, site with transactions etc. It may work for you in order to monitor what you want.